# Trouble running Python 3+ on Mac OSX Catalina

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to execute python code on my local computer using VSCode. When I attempt to import numpy, pandas etc, I receive "Unable to import 'numpy' pylint(import-error)".

When I look at "python --version", I receive Python 2.7.16.

Have read a few threads that have included uninstalling Python extension, changing the settings.json files to the path of the python 3.8 and changing the bash_profile to export PythonPath, however when I run the code, the errors return and the version returns to Python 2.7.16.

Any ideas on what I have missed?

Comment: How are you installing numpy?

Answer (score 0):

First try running from the console, and instead of using

```
python yourscript.py
```

which runs python 2, run

```
python3 yourscript.py
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, do *not* uninstall any versions of Python that come with the OS.

Comment: No, you shouldn’t do that. Forgot that python comes with OSX